# Align text on both sides

Tags: alignment

I'm rather new to LaTeX and I'm currently having trouble replicating this illustration down bellow. What I am basically trying achieve is making two paragraphs ALIGNED to the LEFT and then align the left one on the left and the right one on the right.

[image: Illustration]

If someone has a solution where each line of the two paragraphs are on the same line I wouldn't mind doing it that way either.

Here's how I've gone so far:

```
Institut Universitaire  Technologique de Blois \hfill\llap{Direction des systèmes d'informations}

DUT Réseaux \& Télécommunications \hfill\llap Conseil Départemental du Cher \hfill

15 Rue de la Chocolaterie \hfill 6 Route de Guerry \hfill

41000 Blois \hfill 18203 Bourges \hfill
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want is not  very clear. Is it the layout of the top screenshot or that of the below one? What about the logos?

Comment: @VinnieJonny you could use tabs

Comment: @VinnieJonny please have look at the answer below, remove the `showframe` command in finals

Comment: @VinnieJonny was there something else required in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\geometry{margin=1in,showframe}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \scriptsize
        Institut Universitaire  Technologique de Blois\\
        DUT Réseaux \& Télécommunications \\
        15 Rue de la Chocolaterie \\
        41000 Blois\\[10pt]
        \includegraphics[width=17mm,height=17mm]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \scriptsize
    Institut Universitaire  Technologique de Blois\\
    DUT Réseaux \& Télécommunications \\
    15 Rue de la Chocolaterie \\
    41000 Blois\\[10pt]
    \includegraphics[width=17mm,height=17mm]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**edit --removing the logo and page margin frames**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\geometry{margin=1in}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \footnotesize
        Institut Universitaire  Technologique de Blois\\
        DUT Réseaux \& Télécommunications \\
        15 Rue de la Chocolaterie \\
        41000 Blois\\
%        \includegraphics[width=17mm,height=17mm]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
    \footnotesize
    Institut Universitaire  Technologique de Blois\\
    DUT Réseaux \& Télécommunications \\
    15 Rue de la Chocolaterie \\
    41000 Blois\\
%    \includegraphics[width=17mm,height=17mm]{logo.png}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty much what I'm trying to achieve. Also, thanks for the extra effort of making a verison with images when I didn't clarify to

Comment: @VinnieJonny  request to accept the answer by clicking the green tick mark on the left side of the answer